# How to check if there is at least 1 day difference between 2 dates

Tags: java, date, compare, gregorian-calendar

So, I have to check if the difference between 2 dates is at least one day. Then the method should return true, otherwise it is false.

The format for dates that I´m using is `GregorianCalendar(year, month, day)`.

So I already have a method that uses `date1.before(date2)`, but that also checks the time, so if`date1` is before `date2` it returns true, even if they are the same day (but the time is different!).

What I need is a way to check if the difference between the dates is at least 1 day.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
public boolean dateDifference(Date d1, Date d2)
{ 
long currentDateMilliSec = d1.getTime();
long updateDateMilliSec = d2.getTime();
long diffDays = (currentDateMilliSec - updateDateMilliSec) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
if (diffDays >= 1) return true;
else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 day to cal1 and test if it's not after cal2

```
    cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    System.out.println(!cal1.after(cal2));
```

Comment: before doing this you also need to check `cal1.before(cal2) == true`